# Magento order with backordered items: set status

Tags: magento, events, grid

Magento order with backordered items: set status

How can I change the order status of an order (after placement and payment) to a custom status of the order contains backordered items

So if a normal order is placed and all is in stock: status New

So if a order is placed containing at least 1 backorder item: status Has backorders

thanks, Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you will have to add your new status at
System > Order Statuses > Create New Status

than create an observer for event `sales_order_place_after`, in its method iterate trough order items collection and check if any of items have negative quantity. If it is the case use setState method on order object and update status.